# Simple way to appending new data to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask, append

Im making an app that shows images from a `Tumblr` account. It loads the first 20 items, and then at the bottom there is a "load more" button. When the "load more" botton is clicked, I use an `AsyncTask` to handle it. I have set everything up as I think it should be, but I fail to append the next 20 images to the list. I have seen some other projects use a custom `listAdapter` class, but I was looking for a simpler way to do it.

Here's my code:

```
public class Example extends Activity {

Context context = null;
ListView listView = null;
TextView footer;
int offset = 0;
ProgressDialog pDialog;

private String searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?api_key=API_KEY&offset=0";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs;
    try {
        tumblrs = getTumblrs();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null);
        footer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFoot);
        listView.addFooterView(v);
        listView.setAdapter(new UserItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem,
                tumblrs));

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    footer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new loadMoreListView().execute();
        }
    });

}

public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tumblr> {
    private ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs;

    public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int imageViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs) {
        super(context, imageViewResourceId, tumblrs);
        this.tumblrs = tumblrs;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

        }

        Tumblr tumblr = tumblrs.get(position);
        if (tumblr != null) {

            ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);

            if (image != null) {
                image.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(tumblr.image_url));
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(String bitmapUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(bitmapUrl);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                .getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Tumblr> getTumblrs() throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException, JSONException {
    searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?api_key=API_KEY&offset=0";

    ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs = new ArrayList<Tumblr>();

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    String responseBody = null;
    try {
        responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);

    JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray(
            "posts");
    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray photos = posts.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("photos");
        for (int j = 0; j < photos.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject(j);
            String url = photo.getJSONArray("alt_sizes").getJSONObject(0)
                    .getString("url");

            Tumblr tumblr = new Tumblr(url);
            tumblrs.add(tumblr);
        }
    }
    return tumblrs;
}

public class Tumblr {

    public String image_url;

    public Tumblr(String url) {

        this.image_url = url;
    }
}

private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Example.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // increment current page
                offset += 20;

                // Next page request

                searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?api_key=API_KEY&offset="
                        + offset;



                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

                String responseBody = null;
                try {
                    responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JSONObject jsonObject;
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);

                    JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response")
                            .getJSONArray("posts");
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONArray photos = posts.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getJSONArray("photos");
                        for (int j = 0; j < photos.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject(j);
                            String url = photo.getJSONArray("alt_sizes")
                                    .getJSONObject(0).getString("url");

                            Tumblr tumblr = new Tumblr(url);
                            tumblrs.add(tumblr);

                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // get listview current position - used to maintain scroll
                // position
                int currentPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                // Appending new data to tumblrs ArrayList


                // Setting new scroll position
                listView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);

            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

 }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you're trying to append to the list, why create a new object for it inside doInBackground() instead of just referencing the global tumblr list and appending it? (global in the sense , as this is just a child class u can still access it)

Comment: @Nithish Inpursuit Ofhappiness
Actually sounds like an idea, but don't know how to set that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Example extends Activity { 

 Context context = null; 
   ListView listView = null; 
 TextView footer; 
 int offset = 0; 
 ProgressDialog pDialog; 
 ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs;
private String searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?   api_key=API_KEY&offset=0"; 

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.main);  
try { 
    tumblrs = getTumblrs(); 
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); 
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null); 
    footer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFoot); 
    listView.addFooterView(v); 
    listView.setAdapter(new UserItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem)); 

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} catch (JSONException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} 

footer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        new loadMoreListView().execute(); 
    } 
}); 



public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tumblr> { 

public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int imageViewResourceId) { 
    super(context, imageViewResourceId, tumblrs); 
} 

@Override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    View v = convertView; 
    if (v == null) { 

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null); 

    } 

    Tumblr tumblr = tumblrs.get(position); 
    if (tumblr != null) { 

        ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar); 

        if (image != null) { 
            image.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(tumblr.image_url)); 
        } 
    } 
    return v; 
} 
} 


public Bitmap getBitmap(String bitmapUrl) { 
try { 
    URL url = new URL(bitmapUrl); 
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection() 
            .getInputStream()); 
} catch (Exception ex) { 
    return null; 
} 
} 

 public ArrayList<Tumblr> getTumblrs() throws ClientProtocolException, 
    IOException, JSONException { 
searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?api_key=API_KEY&offset=0"; 

ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs = new ArrayList<Tumblr>(); 

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl); 

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler(); 

String responseBody = null; 
try { 
    responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler); 
} catch (Exception ex) { 
    ex.printStackTrace(); 
} 

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody); 

JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray( 
        "posts"); 
for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) { 
    JSONArray photos = posts.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("photos"); 
    for (int j = 0; j < photos.length(); j++) { 
        JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject(j); 
        String url = photo.getJSONArray("alt_sizes").getJSONObject(0) 
                .getString("url"); 

        Tumblr tumblr = new Tumblr(url); 
        tumblrs.add(tumblr); 
    } 
} 
return tumblrs; 
 } 
 }

public class Tumblr { 

public String image_url; 

public Tumblr(String url) { 

    this.image_url = url; 
} 
 } 

 private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 

@Override 
protected void onPreExecute() { 
    // Showing progress dialog before sending http request 
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Example.this); 
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait.."); 
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(true); 
    pDialog.setCancelable(false); 
    pDialog.show(); 
} 

@Override 
protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            // increment current page 
            offset += 20; 

            // Next page request 

            searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?     api_key=API_KEY&limit=2&offset=" 
                    + offset; 



            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl); 

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler(); 

            String responseBody = null; 
            try { 
                responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler); 
            } catch (Exception ex) { 
                ex.printStackTrace(); 
            } 

            JSONObject jsonObject; 
            try { 
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody); 

                JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response") 
                        .getJSONArray("posts"); 
                for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) { 
                    JSONArray photos = posts.getJSONObject(i) 
                            .getJSONArray("photos"); 
                    for (int j = 0; j < photos.length(); j++) { 
                        JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject(j); 
                        String url = photo.getJSONArray("alt_sizes") 
                                .getJSONObject(0).getString("url"); 

                        Tumblr tumblr = new Tumblr(url); 
                        tumblrs.add(tumblr); 

                    } 
                } 

            } catch (JSONException e) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 

            // get listview current position - used to maintain scroll 
            // position 
            int currentPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); 

            // Appending new data to tumblrs ArrayList 


            // Setting new scroll position 
            listView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0); 

        } 
    }); 

    return null; 
} 

protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) { 
    pDialog.dismiss(); 
} 

}
```

}

This is what i'm suggesting. I've moved the first declaration of `tumblrs` list from the oncreate, up to the activity class itself. I've made the `asyctask` class to be a child class of this activity so that u don't have to pass `tumblrs` as an argument to the `new UserItemAdapter()` . I've removed that argument for you. and regarding `this.tumblrs=tumnlrs` you don't need that anymore. And in case you're using `tumblrs` elsewhere,  refer to the very same `tumblrs` object declared in the Activity class itself. You can even make `tumblrs` to be static as mentioned in the answer above. In fact making it static is the best way to do this.

Comment: Thanks alot, this worked. Just a little extra question, if i would like the list to only show the 20 new images, how could this be done easily?

Comment: have a seperate list for the new images alone. Add this to the tumblrs. when u want to display the new images alone, use the seperate list.

Answer (score 2):

- Make the `ArrayList` as `static`.
- Add the values into the `ArrayList` named `tumblrs` and then do `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter` (here its UserItemAdapter)

///////////////Edited Part////////////////////////////

**This Project of mine has is quite big, so only posting the 2 classes which is important from your point of view....**

**The Adapter Class :**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProductListPojo> {


    Activity a;
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;    
    ArrayList<ProductListPojo> plp = null;
    ImageLoader iLoader;
    public YoutubeImageLoader imageLoader;
    public ProductAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ProductListPojo> listy) {
        super(context, resource, listy);

        this.layoutResourceId = resource;
        this.context = context;
        this.plp = listy;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        iLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        WeatherHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            imageLoader =   new YoutubeImageLoader(context);
            holder = new WeatherHolder();

            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView_PrefImage);
            holder.imgIsPreffered = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView_isPreffered);

            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView_HeadingPref);
            holder.txtprovider = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView_Provider);
            holder.counterParty = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView_counterparty);
            holder.closingDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView_ClosingDate);
            holder.term = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView_Term);
            holder.indexLink = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView_IndexLink);
            holder.investmentType = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView_InvestmentType);
            holder.productType = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView_ProductType);
            holder.li          = (LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_IsPreferred);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
        }


        ProductListPojo product = plp.get(position);

        try{

            holder.imgIcon.setTag(product.getpId());
            imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/Resources/Covers/FullSize/"+product.getpId()+"."+"jpg", a, holder.imgIcon);   

        }catch(Exception ex){

         holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.milkywhite);
        }

        holder.imgIsPreffered.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct);
        if (product.isPref()){

            //holder.imgIsPreffered.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.li.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }else{
            //holder.imgIsPreffered.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            holder.li.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

       holder.txtTitle.setText(product.getOverview());
       holder.txtprovider.setText(product.getProvider());
       holder.counterParty.setText(product.getCounterparty());
       holder.closingDate.setText(dateKoKaro(product.getClosingDate().toString()));
       holder.term.setText(product.getTerm());
       holder.indexLink.setText(product.getIndexLink());
       holder.investmentType.setText(product.getInvestmentType());
       holder.productType.setText(product.getProductType());



        return row;
    }


    public String dateKoKaro(String datu){

        /*Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d.?.?.?.?-.?.?.?.?.?");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(datu);
        String dx = new String();

        while(mat.find()){

            dx = mat.group();
        }

        System.out.println(dx);*/
        String l = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date(Long.parseLong(datu)));
        System.out.println("THE TIME: "+l);
        String[] dxxx = l.split("-");

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Y: "+Integer.parseInt(dxxx[0])+" - "+"M: "+Integer.parseInt(dxxx[1])+" - "+"D: "+Integer.parseInt(dxxx[2]));
        if(Integer.parseInt(dxxx[1])==0){
        c.set(Integer.parseInt(dxxx[0]), Integer.parseInt(dxxx[1]), Integer.parseInt(dxxx[2]));
        }
        else{

            c.set(Integer.parseInt(dxxx[0]), Integer.parseInt(dxxx[1])-1, Integer.parseInt(dxxx[2]));

        }
        Date d = c.getTime();

        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);

        String InDate = df.format(d);

        return InDate;
    }

    static class WeatherHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        ImageView imgIsPreffered;

        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtprovider;
        TextView counterParty;
        TextView closingDate;
        TextView term;
        TextView indexLink;
        TextView investmentType;
        TextView productType;
        LinearLayout li;
    }

    private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {

        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

**The Activity Setting the Adapter to the ListView :**

```
public class ProductActivity extends Activity{

    public APIHandlingClass api = APIHandlingClass.getInstance();
    public static ArrayList<ProductListPojo> apList = new ArrayList<ProductListPojo>();
    public ListView lv;

    int count = 0;
    ProductListPojo pPojo;
    ProductAdapter adpt;
    View mheader;
    View mfooter;
    boolean isInternet = false;
    Intent i;
    Button mbuttFilter;
    Button mback;
    /*Button mbuttonLiterature;
    Button mbuttonQuestion;*/
    Handler h;
    ProgressDialog pd;


    DataBaseHelper dkarkeB = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.productlist);

                /*mbuttonLiterature = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLiterature);
                mbuttonQuestion = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonQuestion);*/

                mheader = View.inflate(ProductActivity.this, R.layout.headerproductlist, null);
                mfooter = View.inflate(ProductActivity.this, R.layout.giraffeimg, null);
                lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_ProductList);
                adpt = new ProductAdapter(ProductActivity.this, R.layout.productitem , apList);

                lv.addHeaderView(mheader,null,false);
                lv.addFooterView(mheader,null,false);
                lv.addFooterView(mfooter,null,false);
                mback = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Filter);
                h = new Handler();

                pd = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
                pd.setTitle("Loading...");


                apList.clear();

                if(InternetAvailable()){ 

                    System.out.println("Net hai");

                   pd.show();

                   DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
                   task.execute();






                }else{

                    System.out.println("Net nahi hai");

                    DownloadWebPageNewTask t = new DownloadWebPageNewTask();
                    t.execute();
                    //adpt = new ProductAdapter(ProductActivity.this, R.layout.productitem , apList);

                    //fillList();
                    /*adpt = new ProductAdapter(ProductActivity.this, R.layout.productitem , apList);
                    lv.setAdapter(adpt);
                    adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
                     AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
                     myAlertDialog.setTitle("--- Network Erro ---");
                     myAlertDialog.setMessage("We were unable to connect to the Internet to download product information. Please ensure you have an active data connection and restart the app.");
                     myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                      public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        arg0.dismiss();

                      }});
                        System.out.println("No Internet Connectivity");

                        myAlertDialog.show();           



                }

                mbuttFilter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Filter);
                /*mbuttFilter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        i = new Intent(ProductActivity.this, ResetActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });*/


                mback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        i = new Intent(ProductActivity.this, ResetActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });



                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {


                        i = new Intent(ProductActivity.this,ProductDetails.class);
                        //i.putExtra("keyAapo", arg2 );


                        i.putExtra("keyAapo", (int)lv.getItemIdAtPosition(arg2) );

                        startActivity(i);


                    }




                });




                /*mbuttonLiterature.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        i = new Intent(ProductActivity.this, GetLiteratureActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });

                mbuttonQuestion.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        i = new Intent(ProductActivity.this, AnyQuestionActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });
                */






    }


    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String response = "";
          parseJson();
          fillList();

          return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pd.dismiss();   
            }
        }, 3000);   


          adpt = new ProductAdapter(ProductActivity.this, R.layout.productitem , apList);

            /*lv.addHeaderView(mheader,null,false);
            lv.addFooterView(mheader,null,false);
            lv.addFooterView(mfooter,null,false);*/
          lv.setAdapter(adpt);
          adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
      }


    /////--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private class DownloadWebPageNewTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String response = "";

          fillList();

          return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                pd.dismiss();   
            }
        }, 3000);   


        adpt = new ProductAdapter(ProductActivity.this, R.layout.productitem , apList);
        lv.setAdapter(adpt);
        adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
      }

    /////--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    public void parseJson(){

        JSONArray jarr;
        dkarkeB.openDataBase();
        dkarkeB.deleteAll();
        dkarkeB.close();

        try {

            jarr = api.go();

            for(int i=0 ; i<jarr.length() ; i++){



                JSONObject jobj = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
                String mainText = new String();
                String provText = new String();
                String couText = new String();
                String fDatu = new String();
                String termText = new String();
                String indexText = new String();
                String insvText = new String();
                String prodText = new String();
                String isPref = new String();
                String jDesc = new String();
                String jCb1 = new String();
                String jCb2 = new String();
                String jCb3 = new String();
                String jCb4 = new String();
                String jspRating = new String();
                String jFRating = new String();
                String jMRating = new String();
                String jFs = new String();
                String jColl = new String();
                String jSIndex = new String();
                String jEIndex = new String();
                String jCashISA = new String();
                String jEquityISA = new String();
                String jDirect = new String();
                String jTransfer = new String();
                String jSipp = new String();
                String jCapitalAtRiskProDetails = new String();
                String jCapitalAtRiskProPercentage = new String();
                String jProValue = new String();
                String jInitialsCharges = new String();
                String jEarlyISATransfer = new String();
                String pid= new String();
                String jOpinionExplanation = new String();
                String jName = new String();
                String jTaxTreat = new String();
                String jDownSide = new String();
                String jProtectionDetails = new String();
                String jEarlySurrender = new String();
                String jOtherCharges = new String();

                try{
                 mainText = jobj.getString("Overview");
                System.out.println(mainText);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{

                JSONObject jProv = jobj.getJSONObject("Provider");
                provText = jProv.getString("Name");
                System.out.println(provText);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                JSONObject jCou = jobj.getJSONObject("Counterparty");
                couText = jCou.getString("Value");
                System.out.println(couText);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                String cloText = jobj.getString("ClosingDate");
                fDatu = giveMeDate(cloText);
                System.out.println(fDatu);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                termText = jobj.getString("Term");
                System.out.println(termText);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                indexText = jobj.getString("IndexLink");
                System.out.println(indexText);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                JSONObject jInsv = jobj.getJSONObject("InvestmentType");
                insvText = jInsv.getString("Value");
                System.out.println(insvText);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                JSONObject jProd = jobj.getJSONObject("ProductType");
                prodText = jProd.getString("Value");
                System.out.println(prodText);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                isPref = BooleanToString(jobj.getBoolean("IsPreferred"));
                System.out.println(isPref);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jDesc = jobj.getString("Description");
                System.out.println(jDesc);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jCb1 = jobj.getString("CashBackTier1");
                System.out.println(jCb1);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jCb2 = jobj.getString("CashBackTier2");
                System.out.println(jCb2);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jCb3 = jobj.getString("CashBackTier3");
                System.out.println(jCb3);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jCb4 = jobj.getString("CashBackTier4");
                System.out.println(jCb4);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }               

                try{
                JSONObject jSP = jobj.getJSONObject("SPRating");
                jspRating = jSP.getString("Rating");
                System.out.println(jspRating);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                JSONObject jFr = jobj.getJSONObject("FitchRating");
                jFRating = jFr.getString("Rating");
                System.out.println("I am the Fitch:"+jFRating);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                JSONObject jMdy = jobj.getJSONObject("MoodyRating");
                jMRating = jMdy.getString("Rating");
                System.out.println(jMRating);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jFs = BooleanToString(jobj.getBoolean("IsFSCSProtected"));
                System.out.println(jFs);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jColl = BooleanToString(jobj.getBoolean("IsCollateralised"));
                System.out.println(jColl);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jSIndex = jobj.getString("StartingIndices");
                System.out.println(jSIndex);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jEIndex = jobj.getString("FinalIndices");
                System.out.println(jEIndex);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jCashISA = jobj.getString("MinimumCashISA");
                System.out.println(jCashISA);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jEquityISA = jobj.getString("MinimumEquityISA");
                System.out.println(jEquityISA);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jDirect = jobj.getString("MinimumDirect");
                System.out.println(jDirect);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jTransfer = jobj.getString("MinimumTransfer");
                System.out.println(jTransfer);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jSipp = jobj.getString("MinimumSIPP");
                System.out.println(jSipp);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jCapitalAtRiskProDetails = jobj.getString("ProtectionDetails");
                System.out.println(jCapitalAtRiskProDetails);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jCapitalAtRiskProPercentage = jobj.getString("ProtectionPercentage");
                System.out.println(jCapitalAtRiskProPercentage);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                JSONObject jVal = jobj.getJSONObject("ProtectionType");
                jProValue = jVal.getString("Value");
                System.out.println(jProValue);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jInitialsCharges = jobj.getString("InitialCharge");
                System.out.println(jInitialsCharges);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                jEarlyISATransfer = jobj.getString("EarlyISATransferCharge");
                System.out.println(jEarlyISATransfer);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{

                jOpinionExplanation = jobj.getString("OpinionExplanation");
                System.out.println("xxxxXXXX"+jOpinionExplanation);
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }


                try{
                pid = jobj.getString("ID");
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }

                try{
                     jName = jobj.getString("Name");
                    System.out.println(jName);
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }

                try{
                    jTaxTreat = jobj.getString("TaxTreatment");
                    System.out.println(jTaxTreat);
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }

                try{
                     jDownSide = jobj.getString("Downside");
                    System.out.println(jDownSide);
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                    }

                try{

                    jProtectionDetails = jobj.getString("ProtectionDetails");
                    System.out.println(jProtectionDetails);
                }catch(Exception ex){


                }

                try{
                    jEarlySurrender = jobj.getString("SurrenderCharge");
                    System.out.println(jEarlySurrender);

                }catch(Exception ex){


                }

                try{
                    jOtherCharges = jobj.getString("OtherCharge");
                    System.out.println(jOtherCharges);

                }catch(Exception ex){


                }

                dkarkeB.openDataBase();


                dkarkeB.insertTitle( mainText,  jDesc,
                        jCb1,  jCb2,  jCb3,
                        jCb4,  jspRating,  jFRating,
                        jMRating, jFs ,  jColl,
                        jSIndex,  jEIndex,  jCashISA,
                        jEquityISA,  jDirect,  jTransfer,
                        jSipp,jCapitalAtRiskProDetails,
                         jCapitalAtRiskProPercentage,  jProValue,
                         jInitialsCharges,  jEarlyISATransfer,
                         provText,  couText,  fDatu,
                         termText,  indexText,  insvText,
                         prodText,  isPref,  pid, jOpinionExplanation,jName, jTaxTreat, jDownSide, jProtectionDetails, jEarlySurrender, jOtherCharges);


                dkarkeB.close();
                }

            System.out.println("SIZE DOES MATTER IN LIST: "+jarr.length());
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    public void fillList(){

        dkarkeB.openDataBase();
        apList = dkarkeB.getMyProductList();
        dkarkeB.close();


        }









    public String BooleanToString(boolean isKaro){

        String holdIt = new String();

        if(isKaro){

            holdIt = "true";
        }
        else{

            holdIt = "false";
        }

        return holdIt;



    }
    public String giveMeDate(String str){

        String s = str;

        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d.?.?.?.?-.?.?.?.?.?");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(s);
        String datu = new String();

        while(mat.find()){

            datu = mat.group();

        }

        String dtx = new String();
        ////-----------------------------------------

        try {

              //String str_date="2012-09-12";
              DateFormat formatter ; 
              Date date ; 
              formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
              date = (Date)formatter.parse(datu); 
              long longDate=date.getTime();
              System.out.println("Today is " +longDate );
              System.out.println("New "+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date(longDate)));
              dtx = longDate+"";
              }
              catch (ParseException e){
              System.out.println("Exception :"+e); 
              }


       ////------------------------------------------
        /*String[] dxxx = datu.split("-");

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Integer.parseInt(dxxx[0]), Integer.parseInt(dxxx[1]), Integer.parseInt(dxxx[2]));
        Date d = c.getTime();

        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);

        String InDate = df.format(d);*/

        return dtx;

    }


    //////----------------------------------------------------Internet-------------------------------------------

    public boolean InternetAvailable() {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // while(isStopMe){
                System.out.println("This is inside ................. :");
                try {
                    if (!checkConnection()) {
                        System.out.println("No Internet Connectivity");
                        ProductActivity.this.isInternet = false;
                        System.out.println("First");
                    } else {
                        if (inetAddr()) {
                            System.out.println("Net Connectivity is Present");
                            ProductActivity.this.isInternet = true;
                            System.out.println("Second");
                        } else {
                            if (mobileConnect()) {
                                System.out.println("THIRD");
                                if (inetAddr()) {
                                    System.out
                                            .println("Net Connectivity is Present");
                                    ProductActivity.this.isInternet = true;
                                    System.out.println("FOURTH");
                                } else {
                                    System.out
                                            .println("No Internet Connectivity");
                                    ProductActivity.this.isInternet = false;
                                    System.out.println("FIFTH");
                                }
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("No Internet Connectivity");
                                ProductActivity.this.isInternet = false;
                                System.out.println("SIX");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Leak ko catch");
                }

            }
        });
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ProductActivity.this.isInternet;
    }

    public boolean checkConnection() {
        boolean connected = false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (cm != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
            for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
                if ((ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI") || ni
                        .getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                        & ni.isConnected() & ni.isAvailable()) {
                    connected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return connected;
    }

    public boolean inetAddr() {
        boolean x1 = false;

        try {
            Socket s = new Socket();
            s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("ntp-nist.ldsbc.edu",37),3000);
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(is);

            while(scan.hasNextLine()){

                System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
                x1 = true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            x1 = false;

        }
        return x1;
    }
    public boolean mobileConnect() {
        boolean conn = false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNet = cm
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if (activeNet != null) {
            conn = true;
        } else {
            conn = false;
        }
        return conn;
    }





    /////-----------------------------------------------------Internet-------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        //adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        System.out.println("The List is: "+apList+"::"+apList.size());
        if(count>0){
        adpt = new ProductAdapter(ProductActivity.this, R.layout.productitem , apList);
        lv.setAdapter(adpt);

        }
        count++;
        System.out.println("The List is: "+apList+"::"+apList.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as i am quite new to this i'm afraid that my programming level is'nt high enough to process without further help. Could you show it in code?

Comment: @Fansher I am at work now, will surely try answer your with the code once i get home......

Comment: @Fansher i have added the code from my project,,,, `there will be many commented lines, please see that you omit them when trying it out...`

Comment: Thaks Kumar, but this is a quite big project. You also  have an adapter class. Is'nt there a way to append to the ArrayList without setting up the adapter class? Just a simple short way that will fit my project?

Comment: @Fansher You will need to change the `ArrayList` which goes in the `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have this piece of code inside u'r doInBsckground() method

```
  ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs = new ArrayList<Tumblr>();
```

Removr  this. And simply do tumblers.add(object). This is enough to populate over the same list instead of creating a new one with the same name which is what u do.

Comment: Sounds just like the solution for my app. I have tried to updated the code with your anserw, but then i get a NullPointerException at the line tumblrs.add(tumblr). I have updated the code in the question so you can see how i did it. If you have a solution to this it will help alot.

Comment: `public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tumblr> {
    private ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs;`  You are declaring the same arraylist tumblrs twice. Inside this method, the list that you have above in ur onCreate() method of ur Example class loses its scope. Remove this declaration too. I mean remove the one in UserItemAdapter class.

Comment: Really having a hard time understanding what you think i should to. As i understand it, you think i should remove this line: 
     private ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs;
But this will give an error as there then won't be a field called tumblrs for this line:
     this.tumblrs = tumblrs;
Have i understod you correctly?